# Alt+Click does not collapse tree of the folder in sidebar

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, sublimetext3

Alt+Click on a sidebar folder used to collapse the entire folder for me on Windows 7 and ST2. Did this behavior change, or is there a problem with Unity here that I need to fix?

Comment: do you have any sidebar-related plugins installed, like SideBarEnhancements?

Comment: Alt+Click is working fine for me (Windows 7, latest SublimeText2 version (2.0.2)). It looks like its a Ubuntu or configuration/plugin based issue.

Comment: Maybe you should report this as bug: https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues

Comment: Nope, no plugins MattDMo. I'll go do that, fnkr.

Comment: Done, https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues/122 thanks fnkr. I'll update here if I hear something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a conflict with Compiz Move Window plugin.

I followed the instructions in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/67539/63492

> Install Compiz Config Settings Manager (sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager in a terminal) and open it.
>
> Once opened, search for a “Move Window” plugin. Select it, and disable or change the first option "Initiate Window Move".

I changed it to Ctrl+Alt+Click and now Alt+Click in Sublime Text 3 works! Yippee!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment on Aditya M P's answer, but running Ubuntu 16.04 and Sublime Text 3, I found that I had to change the first "Move Window" option to Ctrl+Alt+Click in order to get Alt+Click to work in SBT3.

Simply disabling the first "Move Window" option did not work for me.